An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeAvailabilityZones operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
We have followed these steps many times but again error is coming:

Go to your .aws directory under Users e.g. c:\Users\Joe.aws
Two files: configure and credential. Delete both files
Rerun configure: aws configure.

But now also this is showing:
> aws ec2 describe-availability-zones

An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeAvailabilityZones operation:
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials


Is there any solution?

Have you set any AWS-related Environment Variables?

Your path is wrong. Do not use
C:/Users/Joe.aws
use
C:/Users/Joe/.aws
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html
